# Banach contraction mapping to find unique solution of $y(x) = \int_0^1 G(x,s) f(s,y(s)) ds$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Problem statement:** Use the Banach contraction mapping theorem to show that 
$$y(x) = \int_0^1 G(x,s)\ f(s,y(s))\ ds$$
has a unique, continuous solution $y = y(x)$ if

(1) $G(x,s) \ge 0$ for $0 \le x, s \le 1$,

(2) $\int_0^1 G(x,s)\ ds = x(1-x)/2, 0 \le x \le 1$,

(3) $f(x,y)$ is continuous

(4) $|f(x,y) - f(x,z)| \le L|y-z|$ with $L< 8$.

**My attempt at a solution:** So, this *mostly* seems fairly straightforward. We let

$$Ty(x) = \int_0^1 G(x,s) \ f(s,y(s))\ ds$$

and we attempt to show that $T$ is a contraction from $C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$ with the metric on $C([0,1])$ being the sup-norm. $C([0,1])$ is complete w.r.t. sup norm. Now, if $y_1, y_2 \in C([0,1])$, then

$$||Ty_1 - Ty_2||_\infty = \big|\big|\int_0^1G(x,s)\ [f(s,y(s)) - f(s,y_2(s))] \ ds\big|\big|_\infty$$
$$\le \big|\big|\int_0^1 G(x,s) \ ds\big|\big|_\infty||f(s,y_1(s)) - f(s,y_2(s))||_\infty \text{ , by Holder's inequality,}$$
$$\le ||x(1-x)/2||_\infty \cdot L \cdot ||y_1-y_2||_\infty$$
$$\le \frac{L}{8} \ ||y_1 - y_2||_\infty \ ,$$
so, since $L/8 < 1$, $T$ is a contraction mapping.

Now, I think that I'm on the right track here, but I'm missing some details. I'm not sure why $T : C([0,1]) \to C([0,1])$, where I should use assumption (1), and I'm also unsure of whether this implication is justified:

$$|f(x,y) - f(x,z)| \le L|x-y| \implies ||f(s,y_1(s)) - f(s,y_2(s))||_\infty \le L ||x-y||_\infty$$

and I am hoping that someone can help me with those details!

Comment: your condition (4) looks weird to me.

Comment: contraction is okay. self mapping is still open. you need to show that $|Ty(x+h)-Ty(x)| \to 0$ for $h\to 0$.

Comment: do you have the formula for $G(x,s)$?

Comment: I agree, your contraction proof looks fine, with some minor details to pick on. You need to show that $T$ actually maps from $C[0,1]$ to $C[0,1]$.

Comment: @CheeHan if you happen to have time to pick on those minor details, I would very much appreciate it - I'm studying for quals, and I'm trying to really nitpick my proofs! I'll work on the $C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ thing right now.

Comment: I would definitely start with absolutely value instead of the supremum norm, that makes everything looks nicer, and in the end you could just say something like: Now take the supremum on both sides over _______. Also, if you want to use Holder's inequality for the second line, you should have $L^1$ norm of $G(x,s)$ and the supremum norm of $f(s,y_1(s))-f(s,y_2(s))$. Now, use condition (1) to remove the absolute value of $G$, and condition (2) to bound it by $1/8$; also condition (4) for the contraction.